# Prevent a group from deleting document version history

Tags: document-library, versioning, version-history, delete, forms-library

In a Document/Form Library with versioning enabled (SP 2010), it is possible to delete all versions of a particular document/form simply by going to the "Version History" dialog box. This ability obviously could be unwelcome depending on business requirements for retaining sensitive data. How can I restrict the two link buttons to not be available to certain groups using SharePoint permissions or programmatically? Or just hide them in any way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive this functionality by removing "DeleteVersions" permission from the Permission Level of a Group [image]

Comment: Can you please specify where these permissions can be found? Library settings?

Answer (score 0):

https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteid}/_layouts/15/role.aspx
go on this link (add tenant and siteid). create a new permission group.
Click on add a permission level.
there you can find list of permissions. choose permissions as per your need and create a permission level.
after creating permission level go on the follwing link.
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteid}/_layouts/15/newgrp.aspx
create a permission group and select the above created permission level in that group.