# How to disable Delete option from Version History Page?

Tags: 2016, version-history, delete, version

I want to disable the **Delete** option from the Version History Page.

[image]

I have already gone through [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58385) link, but I do not want to achieve this task by modifying existing permissions. Everyone will have Contribute level of permission, but I don't want any user to delete any version.

Is it possible? If yes, then suggest me the way. Any reference link would also be fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of approaches that you can try.

**1. Hide the element**

Use Chrome inspector to find the exact class/ID for the 'Delete' versions link and then hide it using CSS. You need to add this CSS to all the pages (probably adding it to a master page will be a good idea). You will also have to take care of 'Delete All Versions' link.

**2. Override JS function**

From Chrome inspector I can see that 'Delete' versions link calls JS function `DeleteVersion`. You can override it by using below sample code.

```
var oldDeleteVersion = DeleteVersion;
function DeleteVersion() {
    alert("Deleting versions is not allowed.");
}
```

Again, you need to add this JS to all the pages (probably adding it to a master page will be a good idea). You will also have to take care of 'Delete All Versions' link.

Also, may I ask why you cannot modify existing permissions? That will not only be the easiest, but also the recommended option. The options that I have suggested will require you to thoroughly test as you are overriding what is provided by SharePoint.